# JavaScript - Function doesn't throw error when error calls another function

Tags: javascript, database, cordova, web-sql

i freak out... i can't figure out, why this is not working:

```
function errorHandler(transaction, error){
    alert('Error: ' + error.message);
}
function openDb7(){
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova login", 300000);
    db.transaction(insert7, errorHandler);
```

so the `errorHandler` function ist never called. But if i put an alert instead of the function call inside it, its working - it look like this then:

```
function errorHandler(transaction, error){
    alert('Error: ' + error.message);
}
function openDb7(){
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova login", 300000);
    db.transaction(insert7, alert('error inside it'));
```

Maybe someone knows, where my mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
db.transaction(insert7, alert('error inside it'));
```

doesn't mean that the error happened ... it's actualling executing the alert so that the value returned should be passed to the `transaction` function, try this instead

```
db.transaction(insert7, function () { 
    alert('error inside it')
});
```

if the alert doesn't pop out, it means your callback is never called

Answer (score 1):

`alert('error inside it')` is called immediately, not as a callback.

If you want to use `alert` as an equivalent to your callback function you'd need to wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
db.transaction(insert7, function() {
  alert('error inside it') 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "`error`" object in function "`errorHandler`" doesn't have "`message`" property.